# Grapgql Playground Fauna - file not defined, but it is defined

Tags: graphql, faunadb

Hi so I am learning how to use fauna as database for an e-commerce app. This is the first time setting up some schemas and I can't find an example of how to do this.

My schema:

```
type Image {
      src: String!
      alt: String!
    }

type ArtworkEntry {
    name: String!
    category: String!
    price: Int!
    currency: String!
    image: Image
}
```

This is my graphql mutation on faunas graphql playground

```
mutation CreateArtworkEntry {
   createArtworkEntry(data: {
      name: "DDD"
      category: "DDD"
      price: 101
      currency: "USD"
      image: {
        src: "https://www.pexels.com/photo/26938/"
        alt: "https://www.pexels.com/photo/26938/"
      }
    }
  ) {
     name
    category
    image
    price
    currency
   }
}
```

When pressing play I get the following error:
"Field 'src' is not defined by type 'ArtworkEntryImageRelation'.

Please guide me on the right path(I did replace the schema with the new saved changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema, the `image` field within the `ArtworkEntry` type says that the value is an `Image` type. However, it doesn't say how that should happen.

Since there appears to be a one-to-one relationship between an `ArtworkEntry` and an `Image`, the `Image` type should have the `@embedded` directive included, like so:

```
type Image @embedded {
  src: String!
  alt: String!
}
```

Use of `@embedded` allows you to "embed" one type within another, so that a single document exists with nested fields.

With that change, your mutation also needs to change. As is, the error is:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field 'image' of type 'Image' must have a sub selection. (line 7, column 5):\n    image\n    ^",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 7,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To fix that, update your mutation to specify which fields to return within the `Image` type:

```
mutation CreateArtworkEntry {
   createArtworkEntry(data: {
      name: "DDD"
      category: "DDD"
      price: 101
      currency: "USD"
      image: {
        src: "https://www.pexels.com/photo/26938/"
        alt: "https://www.pexels.com/photo/26938/"
      }
    }
  ) {
     name
    category
    image {
      src
      alt
    }  
    price
    currency
   }
}
```

And then the result is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createArtworkEntry": {
      "name": "DDD",
      "category": "DDD",
      "image": {
        "src": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/26938/",
        "alt": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/26938/"
      },
      "price": 101,
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  }
}
```